# How does Shopify make their liquid templates safe (avoid XSS)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, shopify, liquid

Shopify automatically escapes values if they are used in not safe way, but I have not found this feature in [liquid gem](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/).

Example:

**template:** `<div data="{{ user_name }}">{{ user_name }}</div>`

**user_name:** `'" onclick="alert(\'XSS\')'`

**Shopify** renders it as:

```
<div data="&quot; onclick=&quot;alert('XSS')&quot;">" onclick="alert('XSS')"</div>
```

**Liquid gem** renders it as:

```
<div data="" onclick="alert('XSS')">" onclick="alert('XSS')"</div>
```

Ruby code:

```
markup = '<div data="{{ user_name }}">{{ user_name }}</div>'
template = Liquid::Template.parse(markup)

template.render!('user_name' => '" onclick="alert(\'XSS\')')
```

How does Shopify do it?

I know that there is `escape` filter in liquid or I can escape values on back-end. But Shopify's solution looks safer: you don't get XSS vulnerability if forget to encode a value and code looks cleaner: `{{ value }}` instead of `{{ value | encode }}`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how it is "exactly done", but in the Shopify rendered output it seems that user_name was html escaped.

Comment: Almost, they escape when variable uses in an attribute but do not escape in other cases. So, they "magically" escape variables only when it uses in unsafety way.

Comment: Can you please highlight other examples?

Comment: `<div data="{{ user_name }}">` - in this case Shopify escapes the value.

Comment: `<div>{{ user_name }}</div>` - in this case Shopify DOES NOT escape the value

Comment: I believe both are escaped in the combined example you mentioned in the question itself, the thing is that the **&quot;** is shown properly -unescaped- inside the div.